# The following crontab does not run, but it can be run in the terminal

Tags: python, macos, cron

The following script in crontab is not executed, but it can be executed in the terminal
Command: * * * * * /usr/bin/php artisan edit > /dev/null 2>&1
Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe\

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a crontab issue, it says 'ffprobe' as No such file or directory.

In your PHP code if you are using 'ffprobe' directory, try giving this as absolute path and not a relative one. I mean the full path and not partial one. Say for example something like /home/myuser/phpcodes/ffprobe/ and not just ffprobe.

Please try and let me know if this helps.